# $\iota\left(\mathbb Q\right)\subset\mathbb A_\mathbb Q$ is a lattice (diagonal embedding).

Tags: abstract-algebra, topological-groups, adeles

How could I show that the diagonal embedding of $\mathbb Q$ into $\mathbb A_\mathbb Q$ is a lattice?

Here, $\mathbb A_\mathbb Q$ is the set of adeles, and $\iota:\mathbb Q\to\mathbb A_\mathbb Q$ is defined by $q\mapsto\left(q,q,\dots\right)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** To show that $\iota(\mathbb Q)$ is discrete in $\mathbb A_\mathbb Q$ you need to show that if $\iota(q_n) \to 0$ then $q_n$ is eventually 0. Just look at what does this mean in each component.

For relatively denseness, show that 
$$\iota(\mathbb Q) + [0,1] \times \prod_p \mathbb Z_p =\mathbb A_\mathbb Q$$